# FCM topic messaging for a user or business

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

My goal is to allow users to, "Subscribe" to another user/business in my application so all of their followers can receive notifications when they need to know about something like a new post for example. I am sending the notifications with Firebase Cloud Functions.

I am trying to use topics for this but they don't seem to work... I can successfully subscribe but I am getting nothing when trying to send the notification...

Note: I have push notifications already set up and am successfully sending them for things like messages.

```
//here i am subscribing to the user when they accept the request

  exports.friendRequestAccepted = functions.database.ref('/friends/{pendingFriend}/{requester}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const pendingFriend = context.params.pendingFriend;
    const requester = context.params.requester;

    const ref = admin.database().ref(`users/${requester}/notificationTokens`);
    return ref.once("value", function(snapshot){
        const payload = {
              notification: {
                  title: 'You have a new Connection',
                  body: 'Somebody has accepted your connection request. Who could that be?'
              }
        };

        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snapshot.val(), payload)
        // Subscribe the devices corresponding to the registration tokens to the
        // topic.
        admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(pendingFriend)
          .then(function(response) {
            // See the MessagingTopicManagementResponse reference documentation
            // for the contents of response.
            console.log('Successfully subscribed to topic:', response);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
          });


    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
  })




//here i am trying to send the topic notification when a post is added...  

    exports.newPostNotification = functions.database.ref('/categories/{newPost}/')
        .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
          // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
          const original = snapshot.val();
          console.log('informing for', context.params.newPost, original);
          // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
          // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
          // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
          const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'New Post from user',
                body: 'blah blah blah',
            },
        };

          return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(original.userUid, payload)
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });    
          });
```

When subscribing I am getting the success callback, but when trying to send the message to the users subscribed I am getting nothing at all... I can see the topics show up on the FCM console in the dropdown so I know they are there.

I'd appreciate some guidance to help resolve this issue, I have no clue what it is I am doing wrong.

Cheers!

Comment: You're not dealing with promises correctly.  The promise returned from `sendToDevice` you are ignoring completely.  On top of that, you're mixing the use of promises and callbacks with the various APIs.  It'll be easier if you just use promises, and even easier still if you use async/await syntax.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks Doug, I managed to fix my issue... Is there a better way to notify my, "friends list" without topics that is scalable? I cant see anything like whose subscribed to what it's not a good way to work with things...

Comment: @hugger your new question can be another question